# pass data from one swipe tab to another Null Value present?

Tags: android, android-fragments, argument-passing

I try to pass arguments one to another tab in View pager.But value not pass.I have write code in `onTabSelected()` function.but, Only Null value occurred.Please help me.follow my code.

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener  {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }  


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view

        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", "From Activity");
        //set Fragmentclass Arguments
        MoviesFragment fragobj=new MoviesFragment();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

### MoviesFragments

```
public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String strtext=getArguments().getString("name"); // ERROR in NULLPointerExecption

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
        TextView text=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text.setText("Movie");
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

I try to this code but `strtext` error occured in NullPointerException

Comment: You create the MoviesFragment  but you didn't did nothing with it.

Comment: Tnx for replay.I have problem for getArgument is not get value.why?Any code mistake?

Comment: I say again. You create the MovieFragment in onTabSelected but you didn't did anything with it. you need to use FragmentTransaction.replace method to update the Fragment in the ViewPager

Comment: how to replace MovieFragment @yshahak

Comment: does exception occurs when you intent string?

Answer (score -1):

You need to do something like that:

```
 @Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view

    //set Fragmentclass Arguments
    MoviesFragment preInitializedFragment = (MoviesFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MoviesFragment.class.getName());
    if (preInitializedFragment == null) {
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", "From Activity");
        MoviesFragment mFragment=new MoviesFragment();
        mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, MoviesFragment.class.getName());
    } else {
        ft.attach(preInitializedFragment);
    }

}
```

Comment: Error:(89, 33) error: incompatible types: MoviesFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Comment: Which Fragment version you use? The support v4? or the regular one?

Comment: android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: And for the FragmentTransaction ?

Comment: import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

Comment: Cannot change version..again another error occurred

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88655/discussion-between-yshahak-and-raja-priyan).